# ARM BL instruction Calculation, Getting Target Address from Opcodes

Tags: arm, instructions, calculation

How the Target address is calculated in ARM?

```
01F0D9AC    28 7D CB EB         BL 011ECE54
```

How to calculate the address, so we get the address **011ECE54** from these hex bytes **28 7D CB EB**?

Comment: You need to share the references you are using before anyone will help you with this. It looks like homework...

Comment: just for learning purpose and its modding an application not homework.

Comment: We can't help you much without knowing what you already know. Did you look for the definition of the BL instruction in the ARM ARM?

Comment: Yes BL is BranchLink which is equal to call is asm.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical reference for an ARM instruction opcode is the ARM Architecture Reference Manual for the relevant architecture.

From [ARM-v8 ARM](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/ca/DDI0487C_a_armv8_arm.pdf) you can look up the AArch32 T32 encodings for BL.

From section **F5.1.25**,

> Branch with Link calls a subroutine at a PC-relative address, and setting LR to the return address

Encoding A1 shows {cond}{0xB}{imm24}

On the next page, <label> is described:

> For encoding A1: the label of the instruction that is to be branched to. The assembler calculates the
> required value of the offset from the PC value of the BL instruction to this label, then selects an
> encoding that sets imm32 to that offset.
> Permitted offsets are multiples of 4 in the range –33554432 to 33554428

The pseudo code describes:

> imm32=SignExtend(imm24)
>
> ```
> if ConditionPassed() then
> EncodingSpecificOperations();
> if CurrentInstrSet() == InstrSet_A32 then
>     LR = PC - 4;
> else
>     LR = PC<31:1> : '1';
> if targetInstrSet == InstrSet_A32 then
>     targetAddress = Align(PC,4) + imm32;
> else
>     targetAddress = PC + imm32;
> SelectInstrSet(targetInstrSet);
> ```

Your first challenge is to sort out the byte ordering in your dissassembly, knowing that the 'AL', Always or unconditional, condition code is 0b1110.

Then you have to take all 8 bytes (not 4) from your source listing to calculate the target address, but take care to examine how `PC` is used to calculate the return address. This is described in detail in **E1.2.3** *The general-purpose registers, and the PC, in AArch32 state*